# laravel:8 PHP Error: Class 'App\Article' not found in \..vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory.php on line 625

Tags: php, laravel

M TRYING TO make articles using tinker but it gives this error: "PHP Error:  Class 'App\Article' not found in ...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory.php on line 625"   i use this command to make it

```
Article::factory()->count(5)->create();
```

Comment: What laravel version are you using?

Comment: Do you have an `Article.php` file in `app/`, with `namespace App;` and `class Article extends Model`?

Comment: Verify if you have model in your App\Models folder and if you have then import it

Comment: did you try use in tinker put this `use App\Models\Article;`

Comment: @TimLewis yes plz see here https://ibb.co/mc29pNk     paste.ofcode.org/34uRXZVaiZQCNyf4Qe9gGWQ

Comment: @tameemahmadshahzad  yes plz see here ibb.co/mc29pNk paste.ofcode.org/34uRXZVaiZQCNyf4Qe9gGWQ

Comment: If like some help, not put new elements on comments. Edit question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArticleFactory is using the wrong namespace of the model Article.

```
 replace App\Article with App\Models\Article.
```

and ArticleFactory need to be updated like this:

```
'user_id' => \App\Models\User::factory()->create()->id,
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

- check that app/Models/Article.php has correct namespace
- run command `composer dump`
- try `tinker`:

```
php artisan tinker
\App\Models\Article::factory()->count(5)->create();
//or
Article::factory()->count(5)->create();
```

Afterwards, if it is not help, then do step by step official guide:
https://laravel.com/docs/master/database-testing#generating-factories

Comment: @abkrim, pls see comment of author, Article is placed in App\Models [ibb.co/mc29pNk](https://ibb.co/mc29pNk)

Comment: @Den by using your 2nd command after composer dump  "Article::factory()->count(5)->create();"   it says:  "[!] Aliasing 'Article' to 'App\Models\Article' for this Tinker session."

Comment: @proprogrammer its okay because your model `Article` located in 'App\Models\Article' actually.